# Dynamically loop through an Odata collection using SISS

Tags: dynamic, ssis, odata

Using SSIS I am trying to dynamically loop through all of the collections that are available in the following UK Parliament API https://api.parliament.uk/odata/ and then write the data to a SQL table with the same name as the collection.

Ideally I would like the tables to be created on each loop if possible.

I have tried the following so far:

Created a SQL tables to hold all of the collections that I am interested in:

```
SELECT CollectionName
FROM dbo.Collections
WHERE IsActive = 1
```

Using this table I have used a SQL task setup as following:

[image]

The result set is set to a variable called 'Collections': this is an object type

[image]

From there I have created a ForEach loop container, that is configured like this:

[image]

[image]

Within the ForEach loop I have added a Data Flow Task, where I have set the property expressions as below:

[image]

Within the DFT I have added an OData source configured as below:

[image]

Now I get stuck!, I am not sure if a: the above is the best way of doing this and b: how do I dynamically create the SQL table and insert the result of the Odata collection....

Comment: A dataflow task is built upon a design-time contract that lays out the columns and data types between the source and sink. This allows me to change from `current.Sales` to `historical.Sales` easily, assuming the sales table schema is consistent between the two. What a Data Flow does not support is dynamically switching between `current.Sales` and `AverageDailyRainfall.` Those are going to be 2 very different data sets and that is *likely* the situation you're about to encounter once you solve the basic problem of "how do I odata?"